# Method that accepts an instance of the concrete class

Tags: dart

I have an abstract class `Filter` that is implemented by various transaction filters (e.g. `DateFilter`, `AccountFilter`, etc)

```dart
abstract class TransactionFilter {
  String asString();

  bool operator >(TransactionFilter other);
}

// Concrete implementations
class DateFilter implements TransactionFilter {
  DateTime startDate, endDate;
  DateFilter(this.startDate, this.endDate);

  // ⏹ ERROR
  // 'DateFilter.>' ('bool Function(DateFilter)') isn't a valid override of
  // 'TransactionFilter.>' ('bool Function(TransactionFilter)')
  bool operator >(DateFilter other) =>
    startDate.isBefore(other.startDate) && endDate.isAfter(other.endDate);
}

class AccountFilter implements TransactionFilter {
  List<int> accounts;
  DateFilter(this.accounts);
  
  // Same error as above
  bool operator >(AccountFilter other) =>
    other.any((e) => !accounts.contains(e))
}
```

This seems to be because Dart doesn't consider `DateFilter` and `AccountFilter` to be equivalent to `TransactionFilter`.

EDIT: I'd like the `>` operator to strictly be used by classes of the same subtype (e.g. comparing two `DateFilter` instances). How do I do this in the given example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing does not make type-safe sense. Your `TransactionFilter` specifies that all classes that inherit from `TransactionFilter` do have a `>` operator which can compare against any object of the type `TransactionFilter`.

So when you in a subclass define the operator as:

```
bool operator >(DateFilter other)
```

Or:

```
bool operator >(AccountFilter other)
```

This is not allowed since `DateFilter` and `AccountFilter` is more restrictive than `TransactionFilter` (your `DateFilter` class are only allowed to compare against another `DateFilter` and not e.g. `AccountFilter`).

**Update**
Here is an example of how to do it instead using generics:

```
abstract class TransactionFilter<T extends TransactionFilter<T>> {
  String asString();

  bool operator >(T other);
}

// Concrete implementations
class DateFilter implements TransactionFilter<DateFilter> {
  DateTime startDate, endDate;
  DateFilter(this.startDate, this.endDate);

  bool operator >(DateFilter other) =>
      startDate.isBefore(other.startDate) && endDate.isAfter(other.endDate);

  @override
  String asString() {
    // TODO: implement asString
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}

class AccountFilter implements TransactionFilter<AccountFilter> {
  List<int> accounts;
  AccountFilter(this.accounts);

  bool operator >(AccountFilter other) =>
      other.accounts.any((e) => !accounts.contains(e));

  @override
  String asString() {
    // TODO: implement asString
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Comment: To resolve this a Generic Type could be used without losing Type safety ?  Like `abstract class TransactionFilter<T> ` with `bool operator >(T other);` and in the implementing classes `class DateFilter implements TransactionFilter<DateFilter> {` with `bool operator >(DateFilter other)`

Comment: That is a possibility but I don't know what @FloatingRock are going for here.

Comment: The `>` operator should strictly be used by classes of the same subtype. How do I do this in the given example?

Comment: @FloatingRock I have updated my answer with a working example.

Comment: @julemand101 thanks! Curious why the `T` in `<T extends TransactionFilter<T>>` is repeated?

Comment: Well, I am not entirely sure. I must admit I saw it gave me an error and the error did go away if I added the last <T>. But it is properly because TransactionFilter is now generic so if we want to use this class for restrictions we need to use the generic version of the class.